# C++ constexpr function template compiles with non-literal and non-aggregate types. Is this a bug with gcc?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, function-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct NonAggregate
{
    // Non-aggregate due to user defined constructor
    // It is also not constexpr
    explicit NonAggregate(int i) : val_(i) {}
    int val_;
};

template <typename T = int>
constexpr NonAggregate GetNonAggregate(NonAggregate foo)
{
    return foo;
}

int main() 
{
    // Let us pass a random value to the constructor that can only be known at runtime just in case
    std::cout << GetNonAggregate(NonAggregate(std::rand())).val_ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with gcc 10.2, [as seen here in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hjsjbq). This code does NOT compile with clang:

`error: constexpr function's return type 'NonAggregate' is not a literal type`

However if all we do is remove the template from the `GetNonAggregate()` constexpr function:

```
constexpr NonAggregate GetNonAggregate(NonAggregate foo)
{
    return foo;
}
```

Then the code fails to compile with both clang and gcc. Is there anything I'm mising here? This code is not valid C++ yet some portion of the codebase was relying on this behavior with gcc and suddenly failed to compile when we tried to use clang.

I have not yet tested this code with the msvc compiler, I will update this question when I do.

Comment: What problem with msvc on godbolt are you referring to? Also, if you're not concerned with what msvc does, you can just remove the last sentence.

Comment: @cigien When I tried to compile the code sample with msvc on godbolt I get "internal service error". I never had this problem on godbolt and msvc always worked for me, so I assume it's a temporary bug with godbolt itself.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but given that clang and gcc disagree on the code, this could be a msvc compiler bug. You should mention that particular message in the last sentence anyway.

Comment: Until the msvc version successfully compiles on godbolt I will modify that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to [temp#res.general-8.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-8.1)</strike>

> no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or

According to [dcl.constexpr#7](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#7)

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function, that specialization is still a constexpr function, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function when considered as a non-template function, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

And indeed for

```
template <typename T = int>
constexpr NonAggregate GetNonAggregate(NonAggregate foo)
{
    return foo;
}
```

No `T` can make the function constexpr. so the code is ill-formed NDR.

Clang is fine to do diagnostic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, looks like I should file a bug report to gcc.

Comment: Per se. it is not a bug of gcc, as NDR. but it would be a good improvement.

Comment: The quote doesn't apply here. It says it's IFNDR if the template is not instantiated, but OP is instantiating it.

Comment: That is correct, `GetNonAggregate<int>` is instantiated in the example. Also, the quoted statement from the standard refers to the instantiation in the context of a constexpr-if statement which is not present here? The template should have no influence on the outcome of compilation of this program (it should fail in either case), yet it does.

Comment: @cigien: Found [dcl.constexpr#7](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#7) instead of [temp#res.general-8.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-8.1). :)